# Difference between each and select in the below code? ruby

Tags: ruby, iterator

I am still trying to figure out the difference between each and select after reading the documentation.

Can someone explain to me why each and select are replaceable in the below code? 
I don't understand why select is used and then the code-writer places it an array??
Also, what is a good way to understand their differences.

```
def word_unscrambler(str, words)
  str_letters = str.split("").sort

  anagrams = []
  words.select do |word|
    word_letters = word.split("").sort
    anagrams << word if str_letters == word_letters
  end

  anagrams
end
```

Comment: `select` should not be used this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it iterates the same way `each` does, the purpose of `select` is to return a collection based upon the select criteria. In that particular code snippet, it returns a collection based upon the truth value of `anagrams << word if str_letters == word_letters` for each `word` but then discards that collection.

Alternatively, it could have done it this way:

```
def word_unscrambler(str, words)
  str_letters = str.split("").sort

  words.select { |word| str_letters == word.split("").sort }
end
```

As was already said, the author of the code evidently doesn't understand how `select` works.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand why `select` is used

Because the author of that code doesn't understand `select`.